# Azure Data Factory without Azure databricks

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am new to ADF. I am trying to create a ADF pipeline.
I need to run a query on delta tables and send the output csv file to sftp. I should not use Databricks connection. Is that possible ??

I tried using Azure databricks connection. It’s costlier operation my manager says. He asked me to try with out databricks connection.

Comment: Yes, you can use the ADF Delta Lake connector, and something like Dataflows in the ADF pipeline. You'll be able to query the table(s) and output to csv.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delta

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to send the delta table data to SFTP using ADF, then the connection to databricks is necessary**. Without the databricks connection, ADF cannot copy the query data to the target.

**If you are sending the delta table data to SFTP through the code itself** rather than ADF, then you can try the below workaround.

Put all the code in a notebook and create job for that notebook.

[image]

Use the Job Id and execute this job using REST API POST request.

```
URL : https://<databricks_instance>/api/2.1/jobs/run-now
Body:
{
"job_id":<Job_id>
}
Authorization: Bearer <PAT token from databricks>
```

Use web activity like below to do this.

[image]

Web activity will execute the job and returns the `run_id` of the job.

[image]

**Notebook execution:**

[image]

Comment: Please don't answer open-ended, off-topic questions with custom solutions - this is not what Stack Overflow is for. Also, the OP showed no work at all, just a high level requirement.